# Scraping Google App Store for Meta Data

Tags: java, file, web-scraping, google-apps-marketplace

I am noob in Java trying to to build a scraper in a Java which could do the following things.

1. Ability to read data from a CSV file.
2. Use the URIs in that file and scrape the complete App info from the Google Playstore.
3. Export the scraped data and other meta data from the CSV file into an XML file

Can any one guide me in this how to go from here ?
Till now I have made the following three classes

main.java (This is the main method where I call other two classes)

```
import java.io.IOException;


        public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            ReadCVS obj = new ReadCVS();
            obj.run();


            AppInfo obj1 = new AppInfo();
            obj1.readFile();
            }
          }
```

ReadCVS.java (This file reads the CSV file and give the output in a txt file)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintStream;

public class ReadCVS {

    public void run() {

        // Replace the file path to the appropriate path.
        String csvFile = "\\Desktop\\https---play_google_com-store-apps-details-id=.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ";";

        try {

            File file = new File("\\Desktop\\output.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
            System.setOut(ps);

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                System.out.println("URL = " + country[0] + " "

                );

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    }
```

AppInfo.java (This file reads the input from the saved output.txt and tries to out put in the console. But it is not currently working)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class AppInfo {

public void readFile(){
String fileName = "\\Desktop\\output.txt";

//read file into stream, try-with-resources
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

The problem is that whenever I try to run this code the program get hanged and does not terminate.

Can any one help me with my problem ?

Comment: Attempting to scrape Play Store content this will almost certainly get you blocked by Google. It's also disallowed by the [Google Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/): "Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide."

Comment: I am not trying to build a commercial tool. I am just trying to build this for self education. Can you help me with this ?